# How can I improve the efficiency of my domain-name-counting algorithm?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, perl, complexity-theory, hash

First I would like to apologize if this question has been asked. It is difficult to search for the answer w/o finding how to count an array of hash references

My function receives the output from a DBI query, an array of hash references containing email addresses.  The task is to hold a daily count of email addresses by their domain name.  What I do is build a hash of domains to counts. The point is that the array is expected to store at least 10,000,000 emails. The script took several minutes to run.

The question is, could you come up with a way to simplify the algorithm?

```
my ($data) = shift;
my %elements = ( );

foreach my $row (@$data)
{
    my ($username, $domain) = split(/@/, $row->{addr});
    if (exists($elements{$domain}))
    {
        $elements{$domain}++;
    }
    else
    {
        $elements{$domain} = 1;
    }

}
```

By the way, I'm sorry about my English but I'm not a native speaker. Thanks.

Comment: You can add a domain table and add the domain / increase the counter when adding the email to the database (using a trigger?), then you just have to query that table once a day and clear it.

Comment: Do you need to do that quite frequently? why not to use some NoSQL key-value store to hold the addresses as keys and the count as value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the if/else logic. Perl is smart enough to set the count to one the first time you try to increment the count of a key (a domain in this case) that is not yet in the hash.

Lose the if, keep the increment. You probably won't get a huge increase in efficiency, but you'll get a little.  Otherwise, the loop is as tight as it can really get.

Answer (score 1):

There is one optimization you can make **iff** the string contains only one `@`:

```
(split /\@/, $string)[1]
```

is equivalent to, but less efficient than

```
substr $string, 1 + index $string, '@'
```

The performance increase won't be that dramatic if that line isn't executed very often, but in a very unscientific benchmark I just ran, execution time *roughly* halved.

Another difference is the behaviour if no `@` is present — the `split` solution would give `undef`, which stringifies to the empty string, but the `index` solution will give the last character.

You can increase efficiency further if you don't mind a leading `@` in the hash keys:

```
substr $string, index $string, '@'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is already O(N), which is about as efficient as an counting algorithm is going to get.  You could make micro optimizations like eliminating the `if` clause, but you're not going to get any algorithmic improvement.

Comment: It's merely O(N). If you want to factor the length the string, it would be O(N*L), but that would be silly.

Comment: @ikegami I'm always kind of unsure of the complexity of hash insertion and so model it as log n.  I should probably not do that.

Comment: @darch hashing is roughly *O(L)* where *L* is the length of the key, for long keys. The actual insertion is *O(1)* under low hash load. As we assume or keys to be of almost constant length, we have *O(1)* effectively.